# fixed position div inside div container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create fixed position div inside relative container. I am using bootstrap css framework. I am trying to create a fixed position cart. So whenever user scroll page it will show cart contents. but now problem is, it ran outside that container div.

This has to work in responsive mode.

Here my try:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.element {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element">
      fixed
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did the answers work for you ?

Comment: nope :( i have tried these before my post.

Comment: I gave you a jsfiddle for a working demo..how come that didnt work ?

Comment: your demo works but not in responsive modes

Comment: **Googlers:** make sure you're not setting e.g. both `left` and `top` while also using `position: fixed`; otherwise, you're overriding it completely.

Answer (score 4):

Screenshot:

[image]

This is how `position: fixed;` behaves:

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
> specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move
> when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
> every page.

Hence, to get what you want you have to use something more than fixed positioning:

Probably this:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.element {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: 0px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element">
      fixed
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to that :

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="inContainer">
            <p> coucou </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p> other thing</p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

You want that `class="inContainer"` are in `class="Container"` in fixed position but if you scroll with the navigator scroll you don't want that the `class="inContainer"` move outside the `class="container"`

So you can make something like that

```css
.container{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.inContainer {
    position: absolute; 
}
```

So class=inContainer will be always on the top of you're class=Container and move with you're class=container if you scroll with navigator scroll =)

(tested only with chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Make the element's parent container have `position: relative`

Instead of using `top` or `left` use `margin-top` and/or `margin-left`

If you only use `top` that will position the element based on the window, but if you use `margin-top` that will position based on the parent element. Same goes for `left` or `right`

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's impossible because fixed property throws the element out of the flow so it doesn't depend to anything on the document and yes it is no more contained in your container : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, just use `margin-top` property instead of `top` property.

> When you use position: fixed and specify a top and or left position,
>   you'll find that the element will be fixed relative to the window, and
>   not to any other element of position: relative.
>
> There is a way around this and that is not to specify top and left
>   positions but instead to use margin-left and margin-top on the
>   position: fixed element.

Source: https://www.gravitywell.co.uk/latest/design/posts/css-tip-fixed-positioning-inside-a-relative-container/

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the positioning is mentioned in the  AdityaSaxena's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285591/5746301

For creating a fixed position cart, you can also do it with using the jquery.

If we apply the **Left** or **right** value or **margin**, we may face some issue while responsive.

In the below snippet, I have placed the **fixed** element at the right of the container.

Even if the width of the container increased the fixed element placed accordingly.

Here is the [jsfiddle Demo URL](http://jsfiddle.net/swasatz/166gL9oc/7/)

```js
//Jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
var containerWidth = $(".container").outerWidth();
var elementWidth = $(".element").outerWidth();
var containerOffsetLeft = $(".container").offset().left;
var containerOffsetRight = containerOffsetLeft + containerWidth - elementWidth;
 $(".element").css("left", containerOffsetRight);
});
```

```css
//CSS

.wrapper {
    width:100%
}
.container {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:900px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.element {
    background:#f2f2f2;
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    top:50px;
    border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="element">
            fixed
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this may help you.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show the cart even when the user scrolls that is fixed then you should use `position:fixed` for the cart (if `.container` is your cart), because it should be shown with respect to screen/viewport.  Your current code will only show the `element` which is positioned absolutely inside the `container`. If you want it to be like that then give :

```
.container {
position:relative;
}

.element {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
right:0px;
}
```

Comment: I would like to have a frozen header but with absolute it scrolls along

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;">
  <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute;right: 40px;bottom: 40px;background:#6cb975;border-radius: 50%;width: 40px;text-align: center;height: 50px;color: #fff;line-height: 50px;">
      F
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just add

```
.element {
    left:368px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UUgG4/