# On scroll cover previous section, no js

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to perform a scrolling effect. 
On scroll, the next page section should cover the current one.
So the current section is docked to the top of the screen and while the next section arrives the current is progressively covered but doesn't move.

Basically I am trying to reproduce the effect I found on this website:
http://www.squarespace.com/seven/interface

It works only with css (I tried with js disabled)

I've tried to reverse engineer it but I am not successful so far.

If someone had so advices I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: possibly `position:fixed;` and `background-attachment:fixed;` with CSS

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. But that's not how they do it on the website.

Comment: it doesn't have to be exactly as it is on the website. use your imagination!

Comment: I know but if you want to use position: fixed, you'll have to track the position of the sections and change the property using javascript. This works perfectly smooth so I'd like to take it as a base and work on it.

Comment: You say you disabled javascript, and it worked. I just disabled javascript and on refreshing the page I received a white screen. Did you refresh when you disabled? The page is most likely using JS to apply some base heights because heights cannot be defined in percentages without a parent defined in pixels.

Comment: You need to open the console and remove the opacity 0 on applied to the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea is that every `<section>` has height and `position: relative` and 'overflow: hidden'. But every tag inside those sections has `position: fixed`.

Comment: I thought it was working but after some tests and research. Fixed element are not related to their parents.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285473/fixed-position-div-inside-div-container

Comment: So basically you need to place all your elements where you want them in the page for each section. Then you need set `overflow hidden` on each section. And finally you have to play with the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking at the site with JavaScript turned off and got nothing but a blank screen and a scroll bar (same in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari/iOS).  Furthermore, Chrome tells me that all kinds of functions get called as you scroll.  Unless there is some serious trickery here, squarespace.com seems to be using JavaScript.

Though you may be able to pull of something like the checkbox-hack to set and/or animate the `top` of different sections, I don't think the result for the minority of users validates the development time.

I put together a small fiddle which should help you on your way if you want something like the website you linked to.  Notice that this is still usable if you disable or comment out the JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/kx94my17/1/

Comment: You need to remove the property opacity: 0 on the body when you disable the javascript.

Comment: @nimzur I'm not sure what you mean.  It looks ok to me and works on Safari without js.

Comment: You said you had a blank space when you disabled the javascript.
I was talking about their website. Your example works. Thank you.