# How to have a div fixed only inside one div and change to position: absolute when it starts overlapping with following div

Tags: html, css

Say I have three `divs` like following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
       container1
        <div class="element">
            fixed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
      container2
    </div>
</div>
```

I want div: `element` to be fixed when it is inside div: `container`, but its position should become `absolute` when div: `container2` becomes visible, it should not overlap with div - `container2`, but scroll away at that time with div: `container`.

A pure CSS solution is preferable, but if not possible I may go for a JS or jquery solution. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/zq0kkkcx/) for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/zq0kkkcx/), and tried some solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285591/1610034), which are not working.

Comment: Do you want to fix that fixed div to the first container?

Comment: @aavrug Yes, I want it to be fixed in first container, when second container comes I want this to scroll up and not have this in view.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to use javascript to recognize when the scrolling is at a certain point with window.pageYOffset

When it reaches your desired window Y Offset you can start an event that modifies the css value of the positioning from fixed to absolute (by setting the parent container to relative) and bottom at 0.

Check out this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zq0kkkcx/2/

Also, this is the code that I'm talking about:

```
    document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
       if(window.pageYOffset >= 1200){
          console.log("1200");
          // this is where you want your element to become absolute
          // positioned to his parent container
          // write your css changes here and apply them to elements
          // add relative to container and absolute with bottom 0 to element
       } if (window.pageYOffset <= 1200){
          console.log("<1200");
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a CSS solution, here is a trick that you can do using `z-index`. Other than this there is a JS solution.

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100%
}
.container {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:1200px;
  background:#ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container2{
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:1200px;
  background:#fcf;
  z-index: 1; 
}
.element {
  background:#f2f2f2;
  position:fixed;
  width:50px;
  height:70px;
  margin-left:250px;
  border:0px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    container1
    <div class="element">
        fixed
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    container2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't use any js for this solution.

Comment: Can you add JS solution as well.

Comment: Why you need a JS solution If this is done with CSS? In JS you have to track the scroll, width of the first div and then you will able to get the solution.

Comment: because container2 overrides fixed container, I want fixed should be scroll upwards after container2 comes, check [here](https://www.flipkart.com/intex-it-pb-11k-k-11000-mah-power-bank/p/itmec88rrzyrprpf?pid=PWBEC88RWRGZZRYJ&srno=b_1_1&otracker=hp_omu_Deals%20of%20the%20Day_4_11000%20mAh%20Power%20Bank_8331235a-16af-4e7f-9fbc-fc0fb9555cf6_0&lid=LSTPWBEC88RWRGZZRYJHJGUYV) how product image is fixed than scrolls up.

Comment: @saurabh try this https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/h7rspta0/2/. Subtracted ```70``` in offset because the element class ```heigth``` is ```70px;```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a **sticky header**. There is currently no way to make a header sticky at an arbitrary scroll position using pure CSS - you'll have to look into a JavaScript solution to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have update the question: if pure CSS solution is not possible, I will have to use JS or Jquery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is 100% possible to do this without any JavaScript

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc5sbfvd/1/)

Markup should be like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer-scroller">
    <div class="scroll-container">
      container1
      <div class="fixed-header">
        fixed
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="last-container">
    container2
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.outer-scroller {
  height: 140px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-container {
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: #CCC;
}

.last-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #FCF; 
}

.fixed-header {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;  
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

You'll see I've added an `outer-scroller` div.

The next bit is changing your CSS slightly

The new `outer-scroller` div is double the height of your `fixed-header` (for the purposes of this example) and it has an `overflow-y: scroll` on it.

The container inside there is still the same.

The next change is turning your `position: fixed` into a `position: absolute` and then adding padding to the top part of the div you want to scroll in order to push its content "below" the new "fixed" header.

Scrolling over the `outer-scroller` div then makes its content scroll, and because its height is set with an absolute element on top it then scrolls "under" the fixed header.

Once the bottom of its child content `scroll-container` is reached, the whole page then continues scrolling, and you get the illusion of the header disappearing.

The last bit is `pointer-events: none` on the header so that it doesn't scroll away when the cursor is over it (but the div below does)

Comment: But this has created two scrolls, one inside `outer-scroller` and one at window level, which is not desirable for me.

Comment: that's how the trick works, you can get rid of the scrollbars using other methods (like negative margins etc) but for what you described (or, rather, how I read it) in raw css that's the best I can give you right now